# Определение стилей меню

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Есть небольшой скрипт для добавления css свойств для каждого пункта меню

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var icon = [
        'images/okna.png',
        'images/portal.png',
        'images/ico3.png',
        'images/zabor.png',
        'images/navesi.png',
        'images/s.png',
        'images/ico-2.png',
        'images/ico4.png',
        'images/ico7.png',
        'images/ico8.png',
        'images/ico9.png'
    ];

    $('li a').each(function (e) {
        $(this).css({
            'color': 'red',
            'background': '#414141 url("' + icon[e] + '")'
        })

    })
})
```

Подскажите, почему картинки отображаются только на главной странице (index.php)?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что пути относительные. Раз на главной отображается, то добавьте просто слэш в начале

Comment: '/images/ico9.png' - так? вообще не работает

Comment: значит выкладывайте всё о своей конфигурации.
А ещё лучше — покажите.

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт должен быть подключен на каждой странице. Проверьте. А пути тут, я практически уверен, ни при чем. Разве, что у вас всё по директориям растыкано.

Comment: на каждой странице - точно.

Comment: Если на сайте используется ЧПУ, то как раз таки причем!

Comment: Если используется ЧПУ, то тут и слеши могут не помочь. Тут уже надо смотреть чего в .htaccess понаписывали. Возможно под графику там своё правило

Answer (score 0):

> '/images/ico9.png' - так? вообще не работает

Похоже, вы разместили скрипт не в корневой папке сайта, поэтому естественно, что пути не работают. В этом случае скрипт можно изменить так:

```
var RD = '/path/to/script/';
var icon = [
    'images/okna.png'
    // ...
];
// ...
$(this).css({
    'color': 'red',
    'background': '#414141 url("' + RD + icon[e] + '")'
});
```

Comment: не работает - я даже ради интереса переместил в корневой каталог - то же самое

Comment: да покажите же уже свой сайт.

А то мистикой какой-то отдаёт. Но ведь для любой мистики всегда есть разумное объяснение. Так что покажите. Это поможет найти объяснение и решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Поигрался с htaccess, ставил:
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}
> !^http(s)?://(www.)?example.com [NC]
> RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ -
> [NC,F,L]
Не отображает, убираю - все найс) где где example.com понятно другой домен

Comment: на самом деле, сайт у меня на joomla - я подключаю скрипты через index.php. так что скинуть сайт я могу конечно, но это несколько проблемно. 
может дело в том, что главная страница у меня index.php а другие страницы index.php/page ?

Comment: очень может быть, что и в этом. Джумла — это конечно весьма на любителя, но ваша проблема вряд ли зависит от используемой cms. Нужно просто навести порядок в путях. У вас скрипт подставляет в css адреса картинок и применяет этот css. Картинки же при этом отображаются только на главной. Пути относительные. Какие картинки он ищет на других страницах? http-запросы куда отправляет? Тут дело не в cms совсем. Покажете сайт — один беглый взгляд веб-инспектором (или httpfox'ом) — и верный ответ у вас в кармане. А пока мы гадаем на кофейной гуще.

Comment: я проверил веб-инспектором, он ищет картинки по пути /корневой коталог/index.php/images/ - как это изменить?

Comment: Попробуйте к вашим иконкам ставить полный путь. Т.е.
http://www.yoursite.ru/images/okna.png

Comment: прописал, но все равно путь становится website.ru/index.php/images/image.png